# getting undefined data while using getStaticProps() in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting **Cannot read property 'map' of undefined** when using getStaticProps in next.js inside **components/featured-posts.js** but if i use it directly on **pages/index.js** page it shows the results, anybody know why its doing this?

```
export async function getStaticProps(){
  const data = await fetch('http://localhost/newblog/newblogapi/posts')
  const posts=await data.json();
  return {
    props: { posts }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
const FeaturedPosts = ({posts}) => {
 
console.log(posts)

  return (
    <div className="album py-5 bg-light">
      <div className="container mt-5">
      { posts.map(post=>(
        <div key={post.id}>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
          </div>
      ))}
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default FeaturedPosts;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use getStaticProps on pages (files in the /pages directory), not in regular React components. I suggest you get the posts in your pages/index.js file and pass them as props to the FeaturedPosts component.

Comment: Agreed. Even if was allowed, getting data in the component is not good practice. The component should handle its implementation and data should be passed to it for handling.